# How does the arithmetic logic unit actually works?

Tags: logic, alu

In other words, how can energy combined with metal perform logic operations? In the research I've done i'ts always assumed how the 'magic' happens but usually there's a lack of explanation on how can a physical device can 'understand' and perform processes of logical nature. I think would be a good approach to first understand very simple devices as a calculator, but even with that I cannot grasp (and feel absolutely amazed)on how can a circuit be designed in such a fashion that it can perform 'thinking' activities. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this online course: http://www.nand2tetris.org/.

Comment: Thanks @OliCharlesworth i will take a look at it, it seems very promising, but guess i will have to wait 12 weeks till i have the answer myself.

Comment: This is the core of modern computation, the heart of it: how to make circuits emulate thinking activities. How can you type a if / else statement in java and the hardware be able to transmit that on a physical level. This isn't philosophical at all. The conversion of software data into hardware processing it's the most beautiful thing of modern technology to say the least.

Comment: Then read about how transistors work.  Read about how logic gates work.  Read about how an ALU works.  Read about how a CPU works.  Read about how a compiler works.

Comment: Just to be clear, it is not metal but a [semiconductor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor) that is part of the 'magic'.

Comment: Take a better look at the periodic table and you will see that there's a big percent of semicoductors that are in the metal part of it, at least the most important of them (silicon) it's a metalloid. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon